# Cannot iterate through model in ApiCLI

Tags: php, atk4

I am trying to make a simle CLI php script to automate some stuff in my APP. I need to get all items in my database and iterate through them using it's data. My script is as below

```
include 'atk4/loader.php';

$api=new ApiCLI('sample_project');
$api->addLocation('atk4-addons',array(
            'php'=>array(
               'mvc',
                 'misc/lib',
                )
            ))
->setParent($api->pathfinder->base_location);


$models = $api->add('Model_Items');


foreach($models as $model) {

//var_dump($model);
//sleep(1);
}
```

Output is:

```
# php demo.php 
 /var/www/a2/atk4/lib/<b>PathFinder.php</b>:125
[Notice] Undefined property: ApiCLI::$skin
 /var/www/a2/atk4/lib/<b>PathFinder.php</b>:143
[Notice] Undefined property: ApiCLI::$skin
 /var/www/a2/atk4/lib/<b>PathFinder.php</b>:150
[Notice] Undefined property: ApiCLI::$skin
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function dsql() on a non-object in             /var/www/a2/atk4/lib/Model/Table.php on line 112
```

All Help will be appriciated

Comment: After creating my first post on this portal i realized i did not connect do DB


This was missing:
    $api->dbConnect();


Now it works

Comment: Please add this as correct answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

After creating my first post on this portal i realized i did not connect do DB

This was missing:

```
$api->dbConnect();
```

Now it works